# How to have javascript handle all requests to my web site?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very basic `index.html` file which loads my javascript which does all the work. Clicking on links invokes a javascript handler which rewrites the page without reloading it. I am also using `window.history.pushState` to change the URL in the browser window so that if the user does reload the page, the same page comes up. (My page loads a bunch of JSON on startup which creates a noticeable delay, so I want to minimize reloading the page as much as possible.)

Any requests to `mysite.com` are working as expected and I can move around to different pages and add parameters. The URL in the browser changes according to the page you're on and everything is fine - as long as you don't reload the page. If the URL in the browser window is `mysite.com/foo`, it doesn't load index.html and so my javascript isn't loaded. It looks for a directory or file called `foo` and I get a 404.

This seems like a really basic question but how can I make sure that **all** requests go through the javascript?

I could change my urls to use `/foo.html` instead of `/foo` and then create `foo.html` which loads the same javascript as index.html, but that seems like a hack. There may also be dozens of such pages so I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: You can configure your web server to return index.html for all urls that 404, or for anything that matches a particular pattern, etc.; The exact setup will vary depending on your server and/or host. How are you hosting your site?

Comment: Although, I’m not too familiar with them, I think Service Workers might be the only thing that can do this. If not, then this must be done server-side.

Comment: @rayhatfield I'm not yet, it's in early development. Right now I'm just using `python -m http.server`. I haven't even decided on a hosting service yet since I don't like the one I'm with so I may move my existing sites somewhere else.

Comment: Service workers won't help for first time visitors because the service worker won't be registered in the visitor's browser.

Comment: @GraemePerrow by default, it will load mysite.com/foo with 404 if you did not have this html file in your directory. You cant detect/control the request to make them go through your index.html javascript when they loaded on a different path on client side. The solution for this is only by server side. One of the solution is the one provided by Ray. or you may try to use javascript frameworks like Angular/React which has their own Routing module that make the things much more easy to control.